# How to match this specific string using regex in javascript and if its matched then make it empty

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this

`/// cache ml/3/11204_gb.png/// cache ml/3/16917_ar.png/// cache ml/3/52871_au.jpg`

I want to match it with regex and if matched then make the string empty 
So I want to check if the string start with a '/' and ends with '.png|.jpg' then remove/empty the entire string

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: So far I have tried this regex
scriptValue = "/// cache ml/3/11204_gb.png/// cache ml/3/16917_ar.png/// cache ml/3/52871_au.jpg";
var output = scriptValue.replace(/^\/\/\/\s[a-z]+^(png|jpg)$/, '');

Comment: the question is not clear, what parts of the string do you want to match?

Answer (score 1):

Here'e the regex you want:

```
/(\/\/\/ cache ml\/\d\/\d{5}_..\.(png|jpg))+/i
```

- `/` is a special character so we have to escape it like this `\/`
- `cache ml\/3\/\` this part will match **"cache ml\3\"** exactly assuming its a stable
- `\d{5}` will match any 5 digits
- `..` matches any 2 characters
- `.` is a special character so we have to escape it like this `\.`
- `(png|jpg)` will match png or jpg
- we group the whole thing in a group `()` and use `+` this mean one or more so the regex will match any number of repetitions above one, not just 3 as your example
- we use `i` at the end to make the regex case insensitive.

**Now that we have the regex, we use it like this**

```js
var myString = "/// cache ml/\d/11204_gb.png/// cache ml/3/16917_ar.png/// cache ml/3/52871_au.jpg"
var myRegex = /(\/\/\/ cache ml\/3\/\d{5}_..\.(png|jpg))+/i
var newString = myString.replace(myRegex, "")
```

---

to make the matching more loss when it comes to filenames you can replace `d{5}_..` with `.*` so the regex becomes:

```
/(\/\/\/ cache ml\/\d\/.*\.(png|jpg))+/i
```

this will natch **any file name** with png or jpg extension.

Comment: your code really works but I have one exception that is 
52871_au this name is dynamic; this could be any file name. Can you please change the code accordingly and help me out?

Comment: updated the answer, using `.*` in place of filename should do the trick. good luck :)

Comment: don't forget to accept answer and vote up if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all finally I fix the regex and here it is

```
var text = scriptValue.replace(/(\/\/\/ cache ml\/\d\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif))+/i, '');
```

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]*` this can be replaced with `.*` so it will match any digit or character in whatever language, not just Latin letters. and since we use the `i` flag you dont need to use `a-zA-Z`